# Pandas grouping and combining rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a large DataFrame that looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Date           Category        Location       ImpactRate |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-04-22     Outage          MT               0.05194  |
| 2018-04-22     Outage          ND               0.02552  |
| 2018-04-22     Outage          SD               0.09962  |
| 2018-04-24     Transport       TX               0.03111  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is create the following output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Date           Category        ImpactRate        Break Down             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-04-22     Outage          0.17708           MT (29.3%) SD (14.4%) ND (56.3%) |
| 2018-04-24    Transport       0.03111            TX (100.0%)                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**First Attempt - GroupBy**

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('Date')['ImpactRate'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=df['Location'])'
```

This creates a DataFrame that will contain NaNs where each Location isn't present and creates additional columns that require formatting.

**Second Attempt - Loop using itertuples():**

```
r = []
for item in df.itertuples():
    temp_x = df.loc[((df['Category'] == item[2]) & (df['Date'] == item[1]))
    for i in range(temp_x.shape[0]):
        r.append(temp_x['ImpactRate'].iloc[i])
```

This creates one giant list of ImpactRate - which takes me back to square one.

I don't know enough to understand how to troubleshoot this. I'm guessing I should make a list within a list for each iteration but I keep going in circles. How can I achieve this output in the most pythonic way? (Please explain so that I can learn!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using vectorised functionality revolving around `groupby.transform`. I have defined `Breakdown` series as lists of tuples, as this is the most flexible format. You can apply specific string formats if you wish.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-04-22', '2018-04-22', '2018-04-22', '2018-04-24'],
                   'Category': ['Outage', 'Outage', 'Outage', 'Transport'],
                   'Location': ['MT', 'ND', 'SD', 'TX'],
                   'ImpactRate': [0.05194, 0.02552, 0.09962, 0.03111]})

# apply ratio
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Category'])['ImpactRate'].transform('sum')
df['ImpactRate'] /= df['Total']

# create tuple column
df['Breakdown'] = list(zip(df.Location, df.ImpactRate))

# groupby to list
df = df.groupby(['Category', 'Date', 'Total'])['Breakdown'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df)

    Category        Date    Total  \
0     Outage  2018-04-22  0.17708   
1  Transport  2018-04-24  0.03111   

                                           Breakdown  
0  [(MT, 0.293313756494), (ND, 0.144115653942), (...  
1                                        [(TX, 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel terribly good about this.. but oh well.

```
d = pd.Series(
    df.ImpactRate.values,
    [list(zip(df.Date, df.Category)), df.Location],
    name='Impact Rate'
)

s = d.sum(level=0)
t = d.div(s, level=0).rename('Break Down')

f = lambda t: ' '.join(f'{l} ({v*100:0.2f}%)' for (_, l), v in t.items())

pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(
    [s, t.groupby(level=0).apply(f)], axis=1
).to_dict()).rename_axis(['Date', 'Category']).reset_index()

         Date   Category                           Break Down  Impact Rate
0  2018-04-22     Outage  MT (29.33%) ND (14.41%) SD (56.26%)      0.17708
1  2018-04-24  Transport                         TX (100.00%)      0.03111
```